# Route with page number not working

Tags: cakephp, pagination, routes

I am making a Gallery that uses CakePHP Pagination. The problem is that when I click on any page number link, I get something like this : `http://localhost/mySite/galleries/displayImages/page:2/sort:GalleryImage.modified/direction:desc`, when I want it to show only `http://localhost/mySite/Gallery/(pagenumber)`. How can this issue be fixed? 
I am using CakePHP 2.4.4.

**routes.php**

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/Gallery', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'displayImages'));
    Router::connect('/Gallery/:page', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'displayImages'),array('page' => '[0.9]+'));
Router::connect('/Videos', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'displayVideos'));    
Router::connect('/Contactos', array('controller' => 'contacts', 'action' => 'contactUs'));

Router::connect('/Posts', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/Posts/add', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'add'));
Router::connect('/Posts/edit', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/Posts/view', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view'));
Router::connect('/Posts/delete', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'delete'));

Router::connect('/Login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/Logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
Router::connect('/Users', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/Users/add', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'add'));
Router::connect('/Users/edit', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit'));
Router::connect('/Users/delete', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'delete'));

Router::connect('/Admin/Dashboard', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'adminDashboard'));
Router::connect('/Admin/Dashboard/Gallery/Upload', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'uploadImages'));
Router::connect('/Admin/Dashboard/Gallery/Delete', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'deleteImages'));
Router::connect('/Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Upload', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'uploadVideos'));
Router::connect('/Admin/Dashboard/Videos/Delete', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'deleteVideos'));
```

**AppController beforeFilter**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    if (isset($this->request->params['page'])) {
        $this->request->params['named']['page'] = $this->request->params['page'];
    }
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view','displayImages','image','ContactUs','Contact','displayVideos');

}
```

**Controller**

```
public $components = array('Paginator');
public $paginate = array('limit' => 15, 'order' => array('modified' => 'desc'), 'contain' => array('GalleryImage', 'GalleryVideo'));

public function displayImages(){
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Galeria de Fotografias');
        $this->layout = 'default';
        $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');

        $this->Paginator->settings =$this->paginate;
        $gallery_images=$this->Paginator->paginate('GalleryImage');


        //$gallery_images = $this->GalleryImage->find('all');
        $this->set('gallery_images', $gallery_images);

    //$image_display = $gallery_image['path']
    }
```

**View**

```
<style>
h3{

  text-align: left;
}
</style>
<h3>Galeria</h3>
<br>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach( $gallery_images as $gallery_image ):?>
    <td align="center" class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block;">
    <?php
        $src =$this->webroot. 'img/Gallery/'.$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['name'];
        echo "<a href=\"".$src. "\" rel=\"lightbox\">".$this->Timthumb->image('/img/Gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['name'] , array('width' => 267, 'height' => 189))."  </a>";
    ?>
    </td>
    <?php $i++;
        if($i==3){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $i=0;   
        }
    ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tr>

</table>
<div class="pagesDiv">
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->first(__('Primeira', true), array());?></li>
  <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''  ,'currentTag'=>'span' ,'class' => 'numbers', 'first' => false, 'last' => false));?></li>
  <li><?php echo $this->Paginator->last(__('Última', true), array('class' => 'disabled'));?></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**specify the path in the routes.php**

```
Router::connect('/Gallery/:page', array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'displayImages'),array('page' =>'[0-9]+'));
```

**and add this piece of code in AppController.php**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        if (isset($this -> request -> params['page'])) {
        $this -> request -> params['named']['page'] = $this -> request -> params['page'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the code and it is still doing the same `http://localhost/mySite/galleries/displayImages/page:2/sort:GalleryImage.modified/direction:desc` Url.

Comment: edit your question and add displayImages() method code, also if you have added params to pagination helper put all here.

Comment: Show us how it looks:  public $paginate = array(..) ;

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot that.

Comment: Have you same result if you comment //$this->Paginator->settings =$this->paginate;

Comment: No, but I get something similar :`http://localhost/mySite/galleries/displayImages/page:3`. Debugging `$paginate`, gives me a `null` value, as well.

Comment: I get that Url with or without the route for the pages, commented.

Comment: I just noticed that commenting `$this->Paginator->settings =$this->paginate;`, like you said, does not show the limit of images that are displayed, specified in `public $paginate`.